# Multiple sub-class that similar but different

Tags: java, oop

I've 2 similar classes, one that receives 1 parameters (lets says int type) and the other receives the same type of parameter twice. For both input I need to have the same check (and throw exception if data isn't good) and both classes will have some functionality.

I thought of creating supertype that will have 2 constructors, one with 1 parameter, and the other one with 2 parameters. That will work but the question, what should be done in case there was the option of having three or more parameter.

So I thought to try here if there is any better option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should be done in case there was the option of having three or more parameter?

Try with [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) that took an arbitrary number of values required you to create an array and put the values into the array prior to invoking the method/constructor.

Read the chapter here on [Varargs](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/varargs.html) from Eclipse.

---

### Java Variable Arguments

arargs is a helper syntax and it enables use of variable number of arguments in a method call. In method definition variable aruguments are indicated by **elipsis (…)** and is called as `variable arity method` and `variable arity parameter` in java language specification. While invoking the varargs method we can use any number of arguments of type specified and separated by comma.

#### Varargs Sample

```
public class VarArgSample {

    static int sum(int i, int... marks) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int mark : marks) {
            total = total + mark;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // invoking with variable arguments
        System.out.println(sum(1, 2, 3));

        // same invocation using an array
        int arr[] = { 2, 3 };
        System.out.println(sum(1, arr));
    }
}
```

#### How Varargs Works?

When invoking with variable arguments, compiler matches the argument list from left-to-right with the formal parameters. Once initial set of parameters are matched, then whatever arguments are remaining are constructed as an array and passed to the method.

In the given example, value ’1′ is passed as argument for variable ‘i’ then there are no other arguments remaining except varargs. So the remaining values ’2, 3′ are constructed as array and passed as parameter. This is how the dynamism is achieved.

---

#### solution

In your case there was the option of having three or more parameter then simply try with

```
MyClass(int i, int j, int... k){}
```